# Is there a design pattern/know good method for managing files?

Tags: c#, sql-server, file-io

I'm developping an inventory management application. Every kind of items I can create inherits a generic base class with some fields(creation date, description, etc). All these items can have documentation files (pdf, text files, pictures, it doesn't matter). These files are stored on a network share openly available. I already have a basic functional prototype that can: ask the user to choose a file, upload it, open it and save related information in a database. Here's a basic example:

```
//choosing and copying the file
string filename;
string destination;
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();                       
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
  filename = dlg.FileName;
  destination = @"\\theshare\Data\Doc\";
  textBox1.Text = filename;//just for test/display purpose
  File.Copy(filename, destination + dlg.SafeFileName);
  SaveInfoInDatabase(dlg);//description, path
}

//open the file with default application, called by a button press
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(destination + dlg.SafeFileName);
```

Before going any further, I've asked myself the following:

1. Should I run this code asynchronously? Biggest file yet is ~50 MB
2. Should I use GUID for filenames instead of their original name or just add a number at the end in case of same file names?
3. How should I deal with duplicates? (let's say 20 differents items all share the same
   pdf documentation)
4. Should I save the absolute path or only the filename and use a const string for the directory?
5. If a file can be modified, should I make a local copy, open it then copy it back, or 
   open the original? Concurrency isn't a big problem, it's mostly reference material.
6. Am I going down the wrong path? There's probably design patterns/guidelines for this kind of task but I haven't found anything significant.
7. Should I open the file in a different way? Maybe ask the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the questions aren't really code related as such but I have experienced problems like you have before so I will take a stab

1. I would say, most definitely yes.  I've made use of the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class for this very purpose, but if you're using .Net 4.5 you can use [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).
2. I ran into the same problem in a previous job, I used GUIDS for the filenames as they are pretty (enough) unique
3. You'll have to clarify on this, if some of the items use the same documentation, maybe you could store a reference to the PDF (after checking whether it exists)
4. I'd store only what you have to.  If the file location is in the same place and it will never change ***(THINGS ALWAYS CHANGE)*** then I don't see any harm in only storing the filename.  Things do change though, be aware of that, so try to make the file location a configurable (app.config, web.config etc)
5. I was transferring business critical files - I used File.Copy, straight from the source to the destination.  I had some additional checks that the file existed on the destination before I marked the Task as completed.  Seemed to be fine most of the time, if it failed for whatever reason, it would just retry until it could copy it.  So you could adapt your application to do the same i.e. Try and copy file, check the file exists, return successful.
6. I think because it's files you're always going to have to handle goofiness around files (locking, exceptions etc).  The best way to manage this is a good framework, start small, just have two folders and write a console app which loops through each file copying it to another directory and then work your way up.  I've not seen a hard and fast guide or design pattern for managing files, but you can make a fairly robust and reusable framework for it.
7. Isn't the user asking you by uploading the file?

Comment: Hey! There was a disclaimer after it!

Comment: yeah ... I can't count the number of times a manager has made that promise, and broken it on the very next release cycle (and sometimes even the same release cycle).

Comment: Noted. Directory path from a config file, filename in DB.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to build systems in the past. Here's how I tackled these questions:

1. Yes. Don't block the UI thread.
2. Use GUIDs / whatever db key you have for file names.
3. Don't. In my application, each file could go through several revisions, and just because one file is a duplicate at version 1.0 doesn't mean they won't diverge in the future.
4. Don't store your filenames directly in the database, especially not absolute paths. Use higher-level code to convert from DB GUID / ID <=> filename.
5. Yes. Never directly modify the source file. You might even want to include a check-in / check-out system to prevent two people from editing the same file.
6. These types of projects can get out of hand very fast if you don't limit your scope from the outset (In truth any software product can). I suggest you make sure this is really what you need before you continue.
7. No. Using the default application on the client system is far easier than any alternative I've seen.